# I need to total of columns in pivot table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @FYEAR datetime='01-apr-2014';
DECLARE @TYEAR datetime='31-mar-2015';

Select * from (
select E.employeeID, E.employeename, S.netpay as n1
,((datename(MONTH,S.paydate)))as ShowDate 

FROM employee E
inner join salarydetail S
on E.employeeid=S.employeeid
Where S.paydate>= @FYEAR AND S.paydate<=@TYEAR and e.EmployeeID=1

) as t1

pivot (MAX(n1) for  ShowDate IN (APRIL,MAY,JUNE,JULY, AUGUST,SEPTEMBER,OCTOBER,NOVEMBER,DECEMBER,JANUARY,FEBRUARY,MARCH, TOTAL ))  as P1
```

I want the total of all the months at the end in a 'TOTAL' column
how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FYEAR datetime='01-apr-2014';
DECLARE @TYEAR datetime='31-mar-2015';

Select *, (APRIL+MAY+JUNE+JULY+AUGUST+SEPTEMBER+OCTOBER+NOVEMBER+DECEMBER+JANUARY+FEBRUARY+MARCH) as Total from (
select E.employeeID, E.employeename, S.netpay as n1
,((datename(MONTH,S.paydate)))as ShowDate 

FROM employee E
inner join salarydetail S
on E.employeeid=S.employeeid
Where S.paydate>= @FYEAR AND S.paydate<=@TYEAR and e.EmployeeID=1

) as t1

pivot (MAX(n1) for  ShowDate IN (APRIL,MAY,JUNE,JULY, AUGUST,SEPTEMBER,OCTOBER,NOVEMBER,DECEMBER,JANUARY,FEBRUARY,MARCH ))  as P
```